# Branch.io Ionic integration / Global Function definition needed

Tags: ionic-framework, branch.io

I am trying to integrate Branch.io to my app and I get this error message:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: DeepLinkHandler is not defined"

I followed their instructions here and added their SDK:
https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/cordova/#start-a-branch-session

In specific I'm supposed to do this:
"Then add the method DeepLinkHandler which will act as our callback when the session beings. The deep link data will be included here:"

```
function DeepLinkHandler(data) {
    alert('Data from initSession: ' + data.data);
}
```

Which is EXACTLY what I did.

I talked with their support, and got to the conclusion that we need to define that function as global, so it will be possible to call it from everywhere.

1. Did anyone that is using Ionic with Branch.io plugin can help me fix it?
2. How can I define a global function in Ionic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to define a global method:
in your app.js at the top of the page, simply add the method:

```
function DeepLinkHandler(data) {
        console.log("inside DeepLinkHandler");
        if (data) {
            alert('Data from deep link: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        } else {
            alert('No data found');
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help, it actually solved my problem and i got the console.log :)

Edit:  It indeed calls it, but now i need to figure out a different problem - how do i call my Services from the global function. Im not sure what the answer is yet.

Edit2:
The idea of solving this is firing an event. Here is the inspiration, a bit of changes and it worked.
https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Cordova-Ionic-PhoneGap-Deferred-Deep-Linking-SDK/issues/128